# show the index number of slides Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app, I've created some slides but I need to show the index number of slides instead of pages.

I want to do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a way of doing this, but you'll need to save your slides in an array in order for this to work. You'll also need a property in your class to show what's the current page.

So in your page `.ts` file:

```
export class YourPage {
  // the current page number
  public page: number = 0;
  // your slides
  public mySlides = [...your slides...];

  // when the slides changes this method is triggered, needs to be +1 since the index starts at 0
  slideChanged = ev => this.page = ev.realIndex + 1;
}
```

And then your page `html` file

```
<ion-slides pager="false" (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($event)">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of mySlides ">
    <!-- your slides code -->
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<p text-center>{{page}} of {{mySlides.length}}</p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like:

HTML:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" paginationType="fraction">
```

Try this

Comment: Nice solution, didn't know that attribute

Comment: @MohamedWahshey i'm not the op, Eraldo should accept it

Comment: @EraldoGuri I mean press on the tick mark on the left side of my answer, ^^ and you're mostly welcome m8

Answer (score 0):

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.ionSlides.length().then(number => {
        console.log(number);
       this.allNumber = number;
    });
}

sliderDoChange() {
    this.ionSlides.getActiveIndex().then(index => {
       this.currentNumber = index;
    });
}
```